# Dialogflow google assistant integration crashes when i deploy to google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es

I tried integrating dialogflow bot to google assistant when I test it in the actions , it says "Sorry, my test app isn't responding right now. Please try again soon."  
'my test app' left the conversation'.

I tried fixing it a lot but it just didn't work. I deployed the chatbot on dialogflow gateway. It works fine there and in the test-console but the chatbot doesn't work when I open it in google actions and try to deploy it to google assistant.

How to solve this issue.

Comment: This is a very generic error, it means "something is wrong". Could you update your question with some more information on what you are trying to do and maybe add any errors from the logs?

Comment: I made a dialogflow bot . It works fine in the test console but as soon as I go to integrate it or deploy it on google assistant, it just doesn't work. It says"Sorry, my test app isn't responding right now"

Comment: Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Updated the question with more information.